# Continuous and compact embedding between seperable Hilbert spaces is always dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

What could be an example of a continuous, compact embedding betweend two seperable Hilbert spaces $H$ and $U$, which is not dense?

i.e. is there a map $i: U\rightarrow H, x\mapsto x$ which is not dense, provided that $i$ is continuous and compact?

Comment: What about the embedding $x \mapsto (x,0)$ of $\mathbb R^1$ into $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: What is your definition of "compact embedding"? There are [different definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/definition-of-compact-mapping) that could apply.